# Django Jquery Ajax Like Section is not working

Tags: django, ajax

I am trying to create dynamic like functionality in Django. But it shows following error:

```
Not Found: /blogs/why-do-we-use-it/{% url "like_post" %}
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='post-list'),
   path('like/', like_post, name='like_post'),
   path('<slug:slug>/', post_detail, name='post-detail'),
]
```

models.py:

```
likes = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), blank=True, related_name='likes')
```

views.py:

```
def like_post(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    is_liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        is_liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        is_liked = True
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'is_liked': is_liked,
        'total_likes': post.total_likes(),
    }
    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('blogs/like_section.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

In post_detail.html, I included like_sectio.html:

```
<div id="like-section">
   {% include 'blogs/like_section.html' %}
</div>
```

like_section.html:

```
{{ total_likes }} Like{{ total_likes|pluralize }}
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<form action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% if is_liked %}
  <button type="submit" id="like" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Dislike</button>
  {% else %}
  <button type="submit" id="like" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Like</button>
  {% endif %}
</form>
{% endif %}
```

In base.js:

```
$(document).on('click', '#like', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("from jquery section")
  var pk = $(this).attr('value');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{% url "like_post" %}',
    data: {
      'post_id':pk, 
      'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
      $('#like-section').html(response['form'])
      console.log($('#like-section').html(response['form']));
    },
    error: function(rs, e){
      console.log(rs.responseText);
    },
  });
});
```

In console logs I found below errors  :

```
The current path, <code>blogs/why-do-we-use-it/{% url &quot;like_post&quot; %}</code>, didn't match 
any of these.
```

I couldn't find a way how it done.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, the title of your question reads "...not working in Docker", however the body of the question does not mention docker at all.   This makes me wonder whether the issue is relevant only when the code runs within a container, or otherwise mentioning docker is misleading

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the subject. Can you please share the corresponding html which gets rendered on the client side?

Comment: @AviNehama,  I've edited my question (with base.js).  If you have any idea or suggestion, please mention it  immediatel.  Thanks

Comment: Actually I was referring to the HTML as retrieved by the client (i.e the browser).  You can right-click the web-page and select 'View page source'.

Comment: @AviNehama, Thank you. It is now working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, so that it may help others who face the same issue.

I modified my code from base.html file as bellow:

```
{% block javascript %}
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.5.0.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/base.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d6a626efdd.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on('click', '#like', function(event){
            $(document).on('click', '#like', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log("from jquery section")
                var pk = $(this).attr('value');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '{% url "like_post" %}',
                    data: {
                    'post_id':pk, 
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    $('#like-section').html(response['form'])
                    console.log($('#like-section').html(response['form']));
                },
                error: function(rs, e){
                    console.log(rs.responseText);
                },
            });
         });

    </script>
    {% endblock javascript %}
```

Let's ajaxify django like button :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this form tag

```html
<form action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method="post">
```

i think thst's the issue here